# How to Create Tables in a SQL Server CE database file using C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am creating a SQL Server Compact Edition database using C# code in a console application. Here is my code for creating database:

```
string con;

string fileName = "MiniProfilerData.sdf";
string password = "arcanecode";

if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    File.Delete(fileName);
}

con = string.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", fileName, password);
SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(con);
en.CreateDatabase();
```

This code generates the `MiniProfilerData.sdf` file

Now I want to create tables in that `.sdf` file. I have a table creation script which will generates tables, here is the script [Click Here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs#L380-L428)

How can I generate tables using that `TableCreationScript` in my `MiniProfilerData.sdf` file?

Any idea?

Comment: What's the issue you are having? Any errors? Or do you just need to know how to run that SQL?

Comment: I want to know, how to run that script using c# code.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient

Comment: I know this. If I place this script in one file say "Script.sql". Then "How can I call/execute this sql file from my application?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the script into individual CREATE statements, the execute each (pseudo-code):

```
var scripts = TableCreationScript
    .Trim()
    .Replace("create", "#create")
    .Split(new []{'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for each (var script in scripts)
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(script);
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to split script into individual CREATE statements?

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. One more question: It gives me an error on clustered/non clustered index syntax. Can you explain me why so? Also it gives me an error: Parsing error on nvarchar(max).

Comment: You have to remove the non clustered/clustered statements, SQL CE does not like them. and nvarchar(MAX) => ntext

Comment: Yes, I have already removed it from script. I just wanted to know. Thank you!